# Using SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and GET in controlling the website flow

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a small website. It's `.htaccess` file is like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

So it redirects all the URLs to 'index.php'. I can get the requested URL and act accordingly :

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
switch($uri)
{
case 'index':
    LoadIndex();
    break;

case 'about':
    LoadAbout();
    break;

case 'Posts':
    LoadPosts();
    break;

default:
    LoadNotFound();
}
```

Say I want to use `$_GET[]` in Index page. That changes the URL, so it fails to load the page.
How can I do that? How can I route my site without affecting `$_GET[]` variables in URLs?

Comment: just parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and strip off everything behind the ?

Comment: OK, so is that it ? Isn't there a simple way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` will be `/index.php` and *not* `index`. `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` also includes the `QUERY_STRING`. So, it might be `/index.php?var1=abc&var2=def`.

If you need only the URI path, try `PHP_SELF` or `SCRIPT_NAME`. But keep in mind, that these will be `/index.php` too, including `/` and `.php`.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
switch($uri)
{
case '/index.php':
    LoadIndex();
    break;
...
}
```

You don't need `QSA` in your `RewriteRule`. From [RewriteRule Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

> **Modifying the Query String**
>   By default, the query string is passed through unchanged.

This means, the `$_GET` variable is available in your PHP script as before.

Comment: But it will cause problems in my existing website's flow. I just want to delete the text after '?' in $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI], But I want to access those data using $_GET[]